# How do I return Database connection through __construct to be used in mysqli_*?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, database-administration

I've my config.php file like this:

```
define ( 'DB_SERVER', 'localhost' );
define ( 'DB_USERNAME', 'admin' );
define ( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password' );
define ( 'DB_DATABASE', 'database' );
class DB_Con {
    function __construct() {
        $con = mysqli_connect ( DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ) or die ( 'Connection error -> ' . mysqli_error ($con) );
        mysqli_select_db ( $con, DB_DATABASE) or die ($con);
    }
}
```

and my State.php like this:

```
include_once 'config.php';
class State {

    public function __construct() {
        $db = new DB_con ();
    }

    public function GetStateId($statename) {
        $result = mysqli_query ( $con, "SELECT State_Id FROM state_master WHERE State_Name='$statename'" ) or die ( mysqli_error ($con) );
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $result );
        return $row ['State_Id'];
    }
}
```

But when I try to call a function `GetStateId()`, it gives me a warning `mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in State.php`.

I also tried `$db->$con` instead of `$con` in `State.php` but same result.

Can anyone tell me how do I refer to original `$con` in `State.php` to be used in `mysqli_*`? I'm trying to move from `mysql_*`.

Comment: You're creating a `DB_con` instance, then throw it away, after that threw its `$db` handle away. You need to assign it to a property `$this->con` in both cases. -- The whole `DB_con` class wrapping is pointless though; just make it a function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modified config.php

```
define ( 'DB_SERVER', 'localhost' );
define ( 'DB_USERNAME', 'admin' );
define ( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password' );
define ( 'DB_DATABASE', 'database' );
class DB_Con {
    private $con;
    function __construct() {
        global $con;
        $con = mysqli_connect ( DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ) or die ( 'Connection error -> ' . mysqli_error ($con) );
        mysqli_select_db ( $con, DB_DATABASE) or die ($con);

    }
    public function getConnection()
    {
        global $con;
        return $con;        
    }
}
```

modified state.php

```
include 'config.php';
class State extends DB_Con{

    public function __construct() {
        $db = new DB_con ();
    }


    public function GetStateId($statename) {
        $con=  $this->getConnection();
        $result = mysqli_query ( $con, "SELECT State_Id FROM state_master WHERE State_Name='$statename'"  ) or die ( mysqli_error ($con) );
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $result );
        $row ['State_Id'];
    }
}
```

Above code will work. I'll show you another way. Thisone is neat code, you can easily understand.

modified config.php

```
    define ( 'DB_SERVER', 'localhost' );
    define ( 'DB_USERNAME', 'admin' );
    define ( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password' );
    define ( 'DB_DATABASE', 'database' );
class DB_Con {
    private $con;
    function __construct() {        
        $this->con = mysqli_connect ( DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ) or die ( 'Connection error -> ' . mysqli_error ($con) );
        mysqli_select_db ($this->con, DB_DATABASE) or die ($con);
    }
    public function getConnection()
    {        
        return $this->con;
    }
}
```

modified state.php

```
include 'config.php';
class State {
    private $db;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new DB_con ();
    }


    public function GetStateId($statename) {
        $con= $this->db->getConnection();
        $result = mysqli_query ( $con, "SELECT State_Id FROM state_master WHERE State_Name='$statename'"  ) or die ( mysqli_error ($con) );
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $result );
        $row ['State_Id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain a bit. Thanks!

Comment: @m3huL - Extra code added, from that you can easily understand

Comment: @m3huL- (still thinking) who is down votted that answer :) :)

Comment: Read the comments of the first Answer!

Comment: @m3huL- i hope you can understand second code without explanations :)

Comment: Yea I understood. It was easy to understand as you said.

Answer (score 2):

```
class State {

    private $_mysqli;

    public function __construct($mysqli) {
        $this->_mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    public function GetStateId($statename) {
        $result = $this->_mysqli->query("SELECT State_Id FROM state_master WHERE State_Name='$statename'" ) or die ( $this->_mysq );
        $row = $this->_mysqli->fetch_assoc ( $result );
        return $row ['State_Id'];
    }
}

$mysqli = new mysqli('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$state = new State($mysqli);
```

Or I guess you can use

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->_mysqli, "SELECT State_Id FROM state_master WHERE State_Name='$statename'");
```

But it's not good practice

Edit: Siride has a good point, so here's an explanation.

When you call new State(), you're basically calling __construct(). So by adding $mysqli as a parameter to __construct, you can pass it in via the parameter. You could also have done it through having a setMysqli function inside state, and pass it in that way instead of on instantiation, but this way you know that you'll always have a connection.

As for why mysqli_query requires $conn as the first parameter. mysqli_query() just wraps around mysqli::query(), so when it's asking for mysqli_query($conn, $sql), it's really just performing $conn->query($sql); on the inside, so you may as well just skip the step and do it yourself.

While you're at learning mysqli, consider that you really should be [binding your params](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for security. Further more, you can read up on how I'm storing the mysqli as a property [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: Please add explanations instead of just a code dump. I'll remove my downvote if you do that.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your answer. I saw that you passed params when creating State object. Does that mean I have to pass params everytime I create a State object? If so, then how about config?

Comment: Yes, it means you have to pass in the mysqli object every time you create State. However, you don't have to pass in the config. If you look at the example, what you do is you set the config inside the mysqli object before creating the state, then you pass in the object itself, so the object already has a state. This also means you're only creating 1 connection on the page, not 1 connection for every State